# My function dont transmit substr c++

Tags: c++

My function:

```
void Object::actionsFace(std::string &line, int &iteration_face);
```

i transmit substr to function

```
actionsFace(line.substr(begin, i), cnt)
```

it does not work.

if i use:

```
        std::string test = line.substr(begin, i);

        actionsFace(line.substr(begin, i), cnt);
```

works correctly.

how use substr to my function?

Comment: don't you mean that you call `actionsFace(test, cnt)` instead of `actionsFace(line.substr(begin, i), cnt)`?

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to bind a temporary, returned by `std::string::substr`, to a non-const reference. You cannot do that, but you can bind to a const reference:

```
void Object::actionsFace(const std::string &line, int &iteration_face);
```

This will pass a reference to the temporary string, but you cannot modify it inside of the function.

Alternatively, you can explicitly make a copy, as with `test` in your example. Alternatively, if you need a local copy of the string inside your function only, you can pass by value:

```
void Object::actionsFace(std::string line, int &iteration_face);
```